# How to copy multiple rows from one table to another table using 2 criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

Please be polite, my first try at MySQL and my first SQL question.

I am trying to copy some rows from one table to another. The old table looks like this: [image]

My new table (already existing) is also having the meta_key '_wpsc_sku' and also has the same sku value in meta_value.

I want to copy the bottom 3 rows from the old table (wpsc_smaak, wpsc_kg-of-st, wpsc_inhoud) into the new table where the meta key in both tables is wpsc_sku with the same value. I have multiple post/products to copy.

So far I got this (not working), just trying to copy 1 field:

```
INSERT INTO `test_data` (`product_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
SELECT `test_data`.`product_id`, `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key`, `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value` 
FROM `wp_postmeta` INNER JOIN `test_data` 
WHERE (`wp_postmeta`.`meta_key`= '_wpsc_sku' AND `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value` = `test_data`.`meta_value`) AND `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = '_wpsc_smaak';
```

I hope this is clear to you guys.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `test_data` 
(`product_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)  
SELECT 
    td.`product_id`, 
    wp2.`meta_key`, 
    wp2.`meta_value` 
FROM `test_data` td
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` wp1 ON 
    wp1.`meta_value` = td.`meta_value` AND wp1.`meta_key`= '_wpsc_sku' 
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` wp2 ON 
    wp2.`post_id` = wp1.`post_id` AND wp2.`meta_key`= '_wpsc_smaak'
```

Notes:
changed subselect table order. Used `wp1` and `wp2` to get `post_id` and `_wpsc_smaak` value respectively.

Comment: Will be always empty, because `meta_key` can not have to values at the same time. The second is `OR`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know i have a collision for `meta_key` but I want to insert `_wpsc_smaak` and its value to the new table and I am not able to get this row based on the sku

Comment: Can you try again? made a few changes

Comment: you are my hero! <3 only changes I had to make was adding wp1 to `meta_key` in the join query

Comment: @LuukSkeur, updated the answer for consistency. Happy to help!